# how to access magento store in Lan using wampserver 2.4

Tags: magento-1.7, wamp

i am working on magento store on local wampserver 2.4 .Ip address of my system is 192.168.15.32.these are my wamp settings

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

E:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.confg

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "E:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.0.4/" 

# to give access to phpmyadmin from outside 
# replace the lines
#
#      Order Deny,Allow
#   Deny from all
#   Allow from 127.0.0.1
#
# by
#
#        Order Allow,Deny 
#   Allow from all
#

<Directory "E:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.0.4/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from ::1
    Allow from localhost
</Directory>
```

and my wamp is online color is green when i put 192.168.15.32 on another pc within lan the wamp page is open and when i click on my magento setup folder it show the error"unable to connect" or "not found" or "forbidden" however other folders on my wamp/www are accessible even phpmyadmin also working
please help me to resolve this issue to access the magento in lan on different systems at same time

Comment: So you are trying to access your machine from another machine on your network?

Comment: yes i want to access my machine from another machine in LAN

Comment: What happens when you try to access a phoinfo() page? Can you access a test.html page to see if you even have a folder that is readable?

Comment: there are some other old projects in my wamp/www and they working except magento and when i put this address in my browser 192.168.15.32 it also works but not accessible from another pc

Comment: My Question is this: When you put an index.html file with some content like <h1>hello world</h1> does it resolve? Like this http://192.168.15.32/index.html

Comment: yes i have test and index.html works

Comment: hello i have test magento 1.9 which seems to be accessable from LAN but 1.7.0.2 is not accessable more over i was not download this magento setup from magento community i purchased a theme and there was a folder Quick Start which contain both magento files and theme files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since magento require a domain name update your hosts file on your local machine

```
Hint: open the Windows HOSTS file (C:\\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) and add: 
192.168.15.32 www.localhost.com
192.168.15.32 localhost.com
```

*Try not to use localhost you may run into other issues later on*

Make sure your WampServer meet magento minimum system requirement and double check your folder setting

Take a look at [Install Magento on WampServer few tricks](https://sites.google.com/site/installmagentoonwampserver/) and [Installing on Windows with XAMPP and WAMP](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing_on_windows_with_xampp_and_wamp)

Comment: i edited my windows hosts file now home page is open but images and css not load.and when i click on any navigation link it again show just localhost/projectfolder and page browser gives error unable to connect

Comment: resolved  after doing above just go to admin panel>configuration>General>web> and in unsecure and secure url put the new url like in my case i put 192.168.15.32